# Why do I get syntax error trying to call super?

Tags: coffeescript

I have a Coffeescript class and a subclass. From the subclass constructor i want to call the super implementation. I do like this:

```
class MyTestAbstract
  constructor: ->
    @created_at = new Date()

class MyTestConcrete extends MyTestAbstract
  constructor: ->
    super
```

But I get the following syntax error:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script-redux/bin/coffee --source-map -i test_class.coffee
Syntax error on line 7, column 10: unexpected '\n' (\u000A)
4 : 
5 : class MyTestConcrete extends MyTestAbstract
6 :   constructor: ->
7 :     super
^ :~~~~~~~~~^
8 :
```

What is wrong here?

UPDATE: Seems to be CoffeeScriptRedux issue. I have created an issue on github: https://github.com/michaelficarra/CoffeeScriptRedux/issues/244

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`super` is not implemented in redux yet.

See the [Progress Wiki Page](https://github.com/michaelficarra/CoffeeScriptRedux/wiki/Progress).

Answer (score 0):

You code works fine with the [newest coffeescript](http://goo.gl/3dqfA2) compiler.

Have you tried making it a explicit call?

```
class MyTestConcrete extends MyTestAbstract
  constructor: ->
    super()
```

Is it possible the line after the `super` call contains white spaces?

Comment: I tried with () with no luck and also check for extra whitespace. Maybe it has to do with CoffeeScriptRedux. I use that to integrate with WebStorm.

Comment: @olegam I think you found the cause of you problem.

Comment: Try to add a comment someone on the bottom of the file. This sometimes helped with older coffeescript versions.

Comment: `super()` and `super` do different things.  They are not direct substitutes for one another.